# Get Id after saving a row in database using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, oracle11g

I am using this code to save a row in database.
The id is not self generated from hibernate.I have a trigger in database which is generating id.
Once i save the row in database through hibernate,i need to get the id generated by trigger for that row.

```
public long saveInspectionMaster(HInspectionMaster s) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactoryCommon.openSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    session.save(s);
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anyway i can get the id after saving row.Because there is no other unique key in database except ID.

Answer (score 0):

try flush/refresh methods then return the id

```
public long saveInspectionMaster(HInspectionMaster s) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactoryCommon.openSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    session.save(s);
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    session.getTransaction().commit();


    session.flush():
    session.refresh(HInspectionMaster s):


    return s.getId();
}
```